# What classes are encapsulated within statsmodels.api?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I couldn't find any documentation specifically on the structure of `statsmodels.api`. I've been using linear models like https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html which is in `statsmodels.regression.linear_model`, but in the examples I've seen you can access `OLS` from `statsmodels.api` instead of importing `statsmodels.regression.linear_model`, so the api seems to be some higher level wrapper for a series of classes.

Is there documentation on what's encapsulated within `statsmodels.api`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html#statsmodels-api - or something more specific?

The details of what (and how) models come into the api are in the [source](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/api.py)

Comment: This one's useful too. I was actually on this link earlier but I somehow missed the list. I was also trying to find how it's implemented internally. I'm kind of confused why users need to have access to things like `statsmodels.regression.linear_model` if there's an API for it.

Comment: `.api` just serves to bundle things together. E.g. `OLS` is defined in [`.regression.linear_model`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/3d3207122797e959a5f1dea4563b68b46bfa49ff/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py#L818) while `.api` only [imports/exports it](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/3d3207122797e959a5f1dea4563b68b46bfa49ff/statsmodels/api.py#L10). I guess it depends on where you are coming from if the all-encompassing api is better/easier or the semantically structured implementations.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Is there an analogous API for sklearn?

Comment: as far as I know sklearn doesn't follow this pattern.

Comment: see also https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api-structure.html for why `api` has been added. Importing `statsmodels.api` is slow if we just want to use some parts of statsmodels.